# Prohibit editing card titles and description for workers

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I am the only who create a tasks for my workers in Trello.
How can I prohibit changing of the task by my workers?
They must only comment and close the tasks.

Comment: What do you mean with "closing a card"? That could be moving the card to another list containing cards *you* consider as closed or done... or might be archiving a card (removing the card from any list).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Anyone who can close cards can also change them/add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

It will not really cover your requirements, but [Trello Business Class](https://trello.com/business-class) provides some additional authorization rights. For example, people can be invited to private boards as observers and they’ll have read-only access. But read-only access does not allow commenting or closing.